# JavaScript Timer: Code Working Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am using a javascript timer on a page, which redirects the user after a finite time. The code is doing exactly what I want it to but it continues to throw errors in the console. The error message I get is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

```
 //Countdown Timer

function CountDownTimer(duration, granularity) {
      this.duration = duration;
      this.granularity = granularity || 1000;
      this.tickFtns = [];
      this.running = false;
    }

    CountDownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
      if (this.running) {
        return;
      }
      this.running = true;
      var start = Date.now(),
          that = this,
          diff, obj;

      (function timer() {
        diff = that.duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        if (diff > 0) {
          setTimeout(timer, that.granularity);
        } else {
          diff = 0;
          that.running = false;
        }

        obj = CountDownTimer.parse(diff);
        that.tickFtns.forEach(function(ftn) {
          ftn.call(this, obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
        }, that);
      }());
    };

    CountDownTimer.prototype.onTick = function(ftn) {
      if (typeof ftn === 'function') {
        this.tickFtns.push(ftn);
      }
      return this;
    };

    CountDownTimer.prototype.expired = function() {
      return !this.running;
    };

    CountDownTimer.parse = function(seconds) {
      return {
        'minutes': (seconds / 60) | 0,
        'seconds': (seconds % 60) | 0
      };
    };

    window.onload = function() {

        var display = document.querySelector(".cdtimer"),
            s6timer = new CountDownTimer(20);

            s6timer.onTick(format).onTick(redirect).start();

            function redirect() {
                if (s6timer.expired()) {
                    window.location.replace("../assessmentportal/sectiontimeout.php");
                    }
                  };

                function format(minutes, seconds) {
                    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
                    display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
                };
    };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because this call `document.querySelector(".cdtimer")` returns `null`. There are 2 possible reasons:

1. There are no element with class name `cdtimer`
2. You are running your script *before* DOM  loaded

Comment: that helped narrow things down for me. Turns out that although I did have an element of class "cdtimer" the javascript was also working on an iframe within the page that did not contain that element. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Is your assignment of `display` actually returning a DOM element? If it can't find anything (typo, perhaps?) it will return `null`.